# Getting error Cannot read property 'addEventListener' while trying to capture click count on a button

Tags: javascript, dom, newrelic

Getting the below error while trying to capture clicks on a link.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
> at Home.aspx:566

Code i am using, this is placed within script tag after few other script tags, its not at the top.

```
document.getElementById('btnFndCntnt').addEventListener('click',function (e) {
            newrelic.addPageAction('Find');
        })
```

Comment: The element is not found in the document, could you check if the `id` is correct, and if the element is well present in the DOM when this code fires, and if you have more details, please update the question

Comment: [Please lookup the error message before asking](https://www.google.com/search?q=cannot+read+property+%27addeventlistener%27+of+null+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Id is correct, i have placed this code within the head tag after several other script tags, can u pls tell how do i check if element is present in DOM when code fires.

Comment: You need to wait for the whole dom content to load before looking for an element. Checkout DOMContentLoaded

Comment: You should know better than us if the element is in the HTML code or added to the DOM dynamically by some JS code. In the first case, simply move the script at the bottom of the file (after all the HTML elements) or in `DOMContentLoaded` as mentioned above. In the second case you can for example test with 2 `console.log`, one at the beginning of your script, the other where the element is created and check which log comes first

Answer (score 0):

I share you this code working you can run your function where i write document.write() function.

```js
document.getElementById('btnFndCntnt').addEventListener('click',function (e) {
           // newrelic.addPageAction('Find');
           document.write("Everything Fine !");
        })
```

```html
<button id="btnFndCntnt">Click Me !</button>
```

Comment: So does it mean i am placing it wrong. Currently it is within Head tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's the position. Browsers start running `<script>` tags on spot by default.
This won't work, because the button itself is not parsed yet, producing the exact message you are asking about:

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("btnFndCntnt").addEventListener("click",()=>alert("clicked"));
</script>
<button id="btnFndCntnt">Clicky</button>
```

While this will:

```html
<button id="btnFndCntnt">Clicky</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("btnFndCntnt").addEventListener("click",()=>alert("clicked"));
</script>
```

However a more standard way (compared to reordering) is to put these initialization parts into event handlers themselves, like an `onload` of `<body>` or something in code:

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
    document.getElementById("btnFndCntnt").addEventListener("click",()=>alert("clicked"));
});
</script>
<button id="btnFndCntnt">Clicky</button>
```

(Here the `<script>` tag could go into `<head>` as in the first snippet, and it would actually work there)